# Count num rows and skip repeated data

Tags: php, mysql

I have this comment system where I want to display how many users have commented.
I have this in my database:

```
id    |    name    |    comment
12         Alex         hello
13         James        hi
12         Alex         hey
```

Namely, the number of people in the database is only 2. I could do this by counting the result:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE commentid = '$commentid'";
$res = mysqli_query($connection,$q);
$number = mysqli_num_rows($res);
```

This would result to `3` since there are 3 comments registered in the database.

Now, how can I make the code skip when done reading the same data, like I want to count how many people commented  - it starts counting - read Alex and counted it - read James and counted it - read Alex again but since "Alex" has been counted already, this would skip - so the result would only be `2`. Is there anyway I could do this? Thanks!

Comment: commentid = '$commentid' ? whre is the column

Comment: read about `group by` and `count`

Comment: See COUNT in the manual

Answer (score 1):

**Use `COUNT(DISTINCT id)`**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM comments WHERE commentid = '$commentid'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT name) FROM comments WHERE commentid = '$commentid'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `DISTINCT` and `COUNT` keywords:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) FROM comments WHERE commentid = $commentid"
```

This query will return the count of all user who commented with the specific `commentid`.